# "instanceof" Property lost while passing data

Tags: javascript, object, openlayers, instanceof

I am creating Feature Object as shown, in file1.js and pass it as a parameter to the function that exsist in another file file2.js

```
const f = new Feature();
console.log(f instanceof Feature) //returns true;
const data = encodeDatatoJson (f);
```

Whereas, when this "f" arrives in file2.js, instanceof returns false.

```
const jsonData = {};
encodeDatatoJson = (f) => {
     if(f instanceof Feature){ //returns false;
         jsonData.f.push(geoJSON.writeFeatureObject(f));
    }
}
```

What could be the possible reason.

Comment: What does console.log(f); output?

Comment: Is `f` being somewhere serialized and deserialized? Serializing an object with JSON.stringify and parsing it back loses the prototype (also, it loses other stuff as well), hence it will not be instance of `Feature` anymore as long as it's being serialized.

Answer (score -1):

JSON.stringify or anything that uses it internally won't be able to keep track of prototype. You have to do it yourself:

```
encodeDatatoJson = (f) => {
   Object.setPrototypeOf(f,Feature);  //you can use __proto__ in webkit browsers
   jsonData.f.push(geoJSON.writeFeatureObject(f));
}
```

Be warned, you will loose non-enumerable properties while stringification, and tons of stuff can go wrong while setting prototype like this.

Comment: He's not using `JSON.stringify` and he wants to check if the parameter `f` is of type `Feature` or something else. Thus `setPrototypeOf` will not help.

Comment: instanceof checks prototype chain. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Comment: @RashadKokash Well Yes, I don't use JSON.stringify anywhere, So, the question was to find reason behind losing instanceof holding true value, besides JSON.stringify

Comment: @RashadKokash,  You are loosing it because you cannot copy an object with its prototype chain. Whether you use stringify or not, the moment you convert an object to a string, the memory allocation to its prototype table structure is LOST.

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin man, he's not converting anything to a string.

Comment: @RashadKokash yes it does. What is encodeDatatoJson (f)?????***, Please post what it does, so we get rid of this ambiguity.

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin encodeDatatoJson(f), just checks if it is instanceof Feature, if Yes, executes geoJSON.writeFeatureObject(f). That's all, as I wrote above. I can not see where, it is losing because through out my file1.js, "f" holds true for instanceof Feature, and once the data is passed, this is just a simple check to see if it still holds true, which is not

Comment: It could mutate, you are not revealing something here. Can you please upload the entire work on jsfiddle or something ?